# Does the set of normal Endomorphisms form a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is a true/false exercise I came across the other day. I have trouble coming up with a counter-example/disproof for this particular statement.

Def (normal): $f\in End (V)$ is said to be normal, if $f$ has an adjoint-endomorphism $f^*\in End (V)$ and $f^* \circ f = f \circ f^*$ holds for $f$ and $f^*$.

**Proposition**: Normal endomorphisms form a Group.

Comment: Well, I think the null endomorphism is normal by that definition, and it can't be part of a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, groups need to have inverses, so I'll restrict the discussion to the set of normal *automorphisms* (invertible endomorphisms).

That said, even these don't form a group.  For example, note that 
$$
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} = \pmatrix{0&2\\1&0}
$$
is a product of two invertible, normal matrices which yields a non-normal matrix.